# Deserialize Big JSON Array

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have a very big JSON Array in an external File (http://gta5multiplayer.de/Upload/VehicleData.json)
I'm using **File.ReadAllText(path);** to get the json which works perfectly.
I created a class and a Dictionary which shell hold the deserialized information. https://pastebin.com/EMi5zpnN and

```
public class VehicleTest
{
    public Dictionary<int, VehicleInfo> Data { get; set; }
    public VehicleTest()
    {

    }
}
```

The deserialization works fine for one object of the array but the whole
array cannot be deserialized with my dictionary.

Do you have any advice to deserialize the whole array?

Comment: So that JSON does not look like its an array.  It looks like `Key-Value` pairs.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deserializing fails because you're missing the root element in your Json file.

Modify your Json file as follows:

{
"Data":{
....
}
}

And it should work.